# What is TargetEnvironment=Unity?

Tags: unity, .desktop

I have a pure Lubuntu 12.10 installation. While looking at some .desktop files in /usr/share/applications I see `TargetEnvironment=Unity`.
One example is in the .desktop file for Google Chrome:

```
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NewIncognito Shortcut Group]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --incognito
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Another example is the .desktop file for Inkscape:

```
[Drawing Shortcut Group]
Name=New Drawing
Exec=inkscape
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

To find out what that means, I looked at [Desktop Entry Specification - freedesktop.org standards](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and at [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles). But neither mentions `TargetEnvironment`. Hence my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TargetEnvironment makes the Shortcut Group (i.e. quicklist item) open only in Unity environments. You could also use the `OnlyShowIn=Unity` keyword.

[Here's](http://www.linux.org/article/view/how-to-create-custom-quick-lists-in-ubuntu-11-10) an old Launcher tutorial that mentions it.

As of [here](http://markmail.org/message/eypvnff4bieqf5bj) `TargetEnvironment` is deprecated.